# Are return statements inside a middleware function a good practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a REST API application. Whenever I want to handle an API route, I usually (if not always) have to put nested `if-else` and `try-catch` blocks to check for bad requests, failure in database queries, non-existent resources, duplicates, etc. This makes my code hard to read and maintain.

I have tried to minimize callbacks by using the `async/await` structure, but my code in the routing middleware always seemed to have at least 2-3 levels of indentation. I would like to find a way that will make the function less nested.

For example, I have the following middleware function:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!error1) {
    try {
      const success = await doSomething();

      if (success) {
        const someString = await doSomethingElse();
        if (someString === 'someValue') {
          // **SUCCESSFUL RESPONSE HERE**
        } else {
          // send some error response
        }
      } else {
        // send some error response
      }
    } catch (error2) {
      // send some error response
    }
  } else {
    // send some error response
  }
});
```

I figure I could do something like this, which would short-circuit the flow of the function as soon as some error pops up.

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  if (error1) {
    // send some error response
    return;
  }

  try {
    const success = await doSomething();

    if (!success) {
      // send some error response
      return;
    }

    const someString = await doSomethingElse();

    if (someString !== 'someValue') {
      // send some error response
      return;
    }

    // **SUCCESSFUL RESPONSE HERE**
  } catch (error2) {
    // send some error response
  }
});
```

My questions are:

1. Are return statements inside a middleware function a good idea/a good practice?
2. What happens when I `return;` or `return someValue;`, anyway? Does Express take extra processing resource to process that returned value and try to resolve it in some way?
3. Which type of error-handling would you recommend in this scenario, snippet 1 or snippet 2?

Comment: You could put all your (validations) in separate middlewares (each type of validation in a separate function maybe), and then using [next()](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) you could go on to the next middleware or to an error handler [Default error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html): `next('error')`.

Comment: Answer to question 2: nothing happens, express doesn't care as you can see here https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/router/layer.js#L95 the result of the function call is ignored. I personally prefer the return statements as it quite often makes my code more readable.

Comment: You could also use the [Conditional try catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) : `try {/*...*/} catch (e if e ...) { /*...*/} catch (e if e ...) {/*... */}`. PS: Only supported in Mozilla according to MDN.